# Get alternate weekend in month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I want to check a set of values of dates if it falls among 1st or 3rd or 5th Monday of any month. How to do it in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, that can easily be expressed by a couple of conditions:

```
WHERE
    DATEPART(weekday,DateToCheck) = DATEPART(weekday,'20120910') AND
    (
        DATEPART(day,DateToCheck) between 1 and 7 OR
        DATEPART(day,DateToCheck) between 15 and 21 OR
        DATEPART(day,DateToCheck) between 29 and 31
    )
```

(I do the `DATEPART(weekday,...` check as above so that I don't have to know what your date settings are on the server - I'm just checking the value against a "known good" Monday)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 SELECT  * 
 FROM    <your_table>
 WHERE   datename(weekday,<date_col>)='Monday'
 AND     DATEPART(day,<date_col>)/7 in (0,2,4)
```

Comment: That assumes English language settings.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: that's True.. the question didn't say otherwise   .. :)